# Get keys from hashmap and store in String array using java

Tags: java, arrays, string, collections

I have created one hashmap. All I need to do is get the keys from the hashmap and store in a String[] array.
This is what I was doing but it's not correct.

```java
 HashMap<String, String> columnHeaders = new HashMap<String, String>();
        columnHeaders.put("Id", "101");
        columnHeaders.put("First Name","AAA");
        columnHeaders.put("Last Name","BBB");
        columnHeaders.put("Country","CCC");
        columnHeaders.put("City","DDD");
        columnHeaders.put("State","EEE");
        columnHeaders.put("Province","FFF");
}

 String[] keyHeaders=null;
            for(Map.Entry<String, String> param : columnHeaders.entrySet()){
            String key = param.getKey();
            keyHeaders = key.split(";");
            Arrays.toString(keyHeaders);
   }
```

***I kept the String[] global because I need pass it to a for loop.***
Could please someone help me with this?

Comment: Why are you splitting the key if none has `;`? If you can use the keys as they are, just use `String[] keyHeaders = columnHeaders.keySet().toArray(new String[0]);`.

Comment: You are overthinking this way to much. HashMap already has a method to return a Set of your keys, and Set has a method to convert itself to an array: `String[] keys = columnHeaders.keySet().toArray(new String[0]);`

Comment: So I don't need this for each loop to iterate through the map?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it like this.

```
HashMap<String, String> columnHeaders =
        new HashMap<String, String>();
columnHeaders.put("Id", "101");
columnHeaders.put("First Name", "AAA");
columnHeaders.put("Last Name", "BBB");
columnHeaders.put("Country", "CCC");
columnHeaders.put("City", "DDD");
columnHeaders.put("State", "EEE");
columnHeaders.put("Province", "FFF");

String[] keys = columnHeaders.keySet().toArray(String[]::new);

for (String k : keys) {
    System.out.println(k);
}
```

Prints

```
State
First Name
Country
Id
City
Last Name
Province
```

Comment: what do we mean by `String[]::new` inside toArray. would you please tell what does it have wrong `String[] keys = columnHeaders.keySet().toArray()`

Comment: Since the stream is of an Object, toArray would return an array of object (e.g. `Object[]`);   But to change to a specific `Object[]` type you need to tell it which type.  I could also have done `String[] keys = columnHeaders.keySet().toArray(new String[0])`.   See the [Collection Interface](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Collection.html#stream()) for more detail.

Answer (score 0):

Try change 101 to "101" or String.value (101)